# Problem with regex_replace in prestashop smarty

Tags: regex, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to use regex_replace in prestashop product_list.tpl. My code is like:

```
{$product.description|regex_replace:".*(?=Kompatybilny)":""|strip_tags:'UTF-8'}
```

I'd like it to show $product.destription after "Kompatybilny" word, but it doesn't work and I don't know why. I've tried different regex functions but still the same - variable doesn't show at all.

Comment: Try `"/.*?(?=Kompatybilny)/su"` instead of `".*(?=Kompatybilny)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect! Works as expected. Could you tell me one more thing? How to make it to show part of variable between 2 words?

Comment: Something like `{$product.description|regex_replace:"/.*?Kompatybilny(.*?)Word2.*/su":'$1'}`?

Comment: Super! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
{$product.description|regex_replace:"/.*?(?=Kompatybilny)/su":''}
```

The regex will match

- `.*?` - any  0+ chars, as few as possible, up to (but excluding from the match) the first occurrence of
- `(?=Kompatybilny)` - the `Kompatybilny` substring
- `su` - `s` means `.` can match linebreak chars and `u` supports Unicode strings.